# Check sugarcrm version in installer

Tags: sugarcrm

I have 2 similar files version file is custom/modules/Contacts/views/view.list.php .
1 file is supported for all sugarcrm versions less than 6.5
Another for version greater than 6.5.
I want my installer to check version & copy file according to the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of Jason Eggers and SugarOutfitter's article [How to Package Version Specific Code](https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/blog/how-to-package-version-specific-code) - it's an excellent how-to on packaging views and files for specific SugarCRM versions. It involves clever use of `$GLOBALS['sugar_flavor']` within the manifest's copy directive.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.You always give some really helpful answers.